# Find a value in a 2d array and move it to another 2d array

Tags: c++

[image]So I'm suppose to search my 2d array and find the locations (row and column number) where the search value occurred and store the row and column number in successive rows of a two dimension array

my instructions
"If the value is found in the data array, store the location (row and columns offset) where found in the data array into the locations array.  Each time you find the value in the data array the location will be stored in the next row of the locations array.  The row offset will be stored in column 0 and the column offset will be stored in column 1 of the locations array.  Search the two dimension data array by rows."

This is where I'm confused

```
            locations[Rsize][Rsize]=data[i][j];
            Rsize++;
```

I don't know how to move the row and column from data array to the new locations array 
locations array row 0 col 0 should have the data row
& locations array row 0 col 1 should have the data column

```
void find_value(short data[][15], short rows, short cols, short locations[] [2], short &Rsize, short searchValue)
{
short i,j;
Rsize=0;
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        if(data[i][j]==searchValue)
        {
            locations[Rsize][Rsize]=data[i][j];
            Rsize++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: `locations[Rsize][Rsize]=data[i][j];` does not match the values or locations asked for in "store the location (row and columns offset) " and "The row offset will be stored in column 0 and the column offset will be stored in column 1 of the locations array.".  Read those carefully, do you understand why?  If yes, fix that and edit your question.

Comment: What's your specific question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah that is what I have been trying to figure out what to put there, I know that is the wrong statement but I am not sure what statement to put there. In a 1d array it would be locations[Rsize++]=data[i] in a single for loop I believe. I have just never used 2d arrays before

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Remember, locations is just an array of arrays. You just want to append an array of size 2 to locations.

You want to change this:

```
locations[Rsize][Rsize]=data[i][j];
```

to this:

```
locations[Rsize][0] = i;
locations[Rsize][1] = j;
```